# MonoTouch: Problems downloading and playing video from external URL

Tags: ios, video, xamarin.ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsurl

I can play a video from the local file system, but can't get it to play from an external URL. No error message. Just a blank dark screen. Any ideas?

```
var movieFile = NSUrl.FromString("http://apps.focusonsound.com/demo/AppleVideos/Xylophone.mp4");
mp = new MPMoviePlayerController(movieFile);
mp.AllowsAirPlay = false;
this.View.AddSubview(mp.View);              
mp.SetFullscreen(true, true);                   
mp.ShouldAutoplay = true;
mp.PrepareToPlay();
mp.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works - but only when I replace your URL with one where a **.mp4** file can be downloaded (e.g. using Safari).

Could your URL simply be dead / outdated ?

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it was the MIME setting on the server. Needed to be set to allow playback of mp4 and m4v movies.